# Apply a function over a list to every other list member

Tags: f#

Let's say I have a starting list

```
let test = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

and I want to add the first element to all of the other elements, then the second element to all of the other elements, and so on, until I end up with something like

```
result = [1, [3; 4; 5; 6]; 
          2, [3; 5; 6; 7]; 
          3, [4; 5; 7; 8]; 
          4, [5; 6; 7; 9]; 
          5, [6; 7; 8; 9]]
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out which `List.n` method is appropriate here or even is there is one.  I know that `List.map` won't do it and I don't think that `List.reduce` or `List.fold` will do it either, as those are both accumulator, rather than individual, functions.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct function in the `List` module you can use easily but there is one that it useful from time to time and that you can easily define yourself:

```
let rec pick xs = 
   match xs with 
   | [] -> [] 
   | (x::xs) -> (x,xs) :: (List.map (fun (x',xs') -> (x',x::xs')) (pick xs))
```

this one will produce tuples with the first component being one value from the list and the second component being what's left of the list:

```
pick [1..5] =
  [(1, [2; 3; 4; 5])
  ;(2, [1; 3; 4; 5])
  ;(3, [1; 2; 4; 5])
  ;(4, [1; 2; 3; 5])
  ;(5, [1; 2; 3; 4])]
```

with this it's not hard to do what you wanted:

```
let f xs = 
   List.map (fun (x,xs) -> (x, List.map (fun y -> y+x) xs)) 
            (pick xs)
```

#### example

```
> f [1;2;3;4;5];;
  [(1, [3; 4; 5; 6])
  ;(2, [3; 5; 6; 7])
  ;(3, [4; 5; 7; 8])
  ;(4, [5; 6; 7; 9])
  ;(5, [6; 7; 8; 9])]
```

Comment: Perfect!  I was able to scale up from my heavily-generalized question to my very specific answer thanks to your examples.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways of doing this. Here's another approach in addition to Carsten's. It's a little less efficient but might be useful in some cases.

First, define the useful function `withoutNth` that just removes the nth element of a list

```
let rec withoutNth nth list =
    match (nth,list) with
    | _,[] -> []
    | 0,(x::xs) -> xs
    | _,(x::xs) -> x::(withoutNth (nth-1) xs)
```

And test it:

```
withoutNth 0 [1..5] // [2; 3; 4; 5]
withoutNth 1 [1..5] // [1; 3; 4; 5]
withoutNth 4 [1..5] // [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

And with that, we can create a `addToSiblings` function that does what you want:

```
let addToSiblings list =
    // helper function
    let addNthToSiblings nth x =
        let addX y = x + y
        let newList = withoutNth nth list |> List.map addX 
        x,newList

    // apply helper function to each element
    list |> List.mapi addNthToSiblings
```

And test it:

```
[1..5] |> addToSiblings 

//[(1, [3; 4; 5; 6]); 
// (2, [3; 5; 6; 7]); 
// (3, [4; 5; 7; 8]); 
// (4, [5; 6; 7; 9]);
// (5, [6; 7; 8; 9])]
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant with tail-recursive functions will need to reverse the list when prepending to the accumulator. Instead of reversing, the function could employ continuations, which can be composed in any order.

This is an example where the outer loop reverses after providing the split-up input list to the inner. The inner loop uses a continuation to process the elements from the left sub-list in one direction, and those on the right side in the other.

```
let applyEachToEveryOther f =

    let rec aux2 k = function
    | [], _, [] -> k []
    | [], x, r::rs -> aux2 (k << fun ys -> f x r::ys) ([], x, rs)
    | l::ls, x, rs -> aux2 (k >> fun ys -> f x l::ys) (ls, x, rs)

    let rec aux ls acc = function
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | x::xs -> aux (x::ls) ((x, aux2 id (ls, x, xs))::acc) xs

    aux [] []

applyEachToEveryOther (+) [1..5]
(* [(1, [3; 4; 5; 6]);
    (2, [3; 5; 6; 7]);
    (3, [4; 5; 7; 8]);
    (4, [5; 6; 7; 9]);
    (5, [6; 7; 8; 9])] *)
```